# Can't upload file with ajax and Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, image-upload, file-upload

I have a form with 3 input file, and I need to upload their files without reload the page. I use formData object but when I take params in Magento controller it return [native code]...

**opcheckout.js :**

```
save: function () {
    var form = $$('#form-doc-popin')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    if (checkout.loadWaiting != false) return;
    // checkout.setLoadWaiting('review');
    var params = '';
    if (this.agreementsForm) {
        params += '&' + Form.serialize(this.agreementsForm);
    }
    params += '&' + Form.serialize('co-payment-form');
    var validator = new Validation('co-payment-form');

    params.save = true;

    formData.append('params', params);

    if (payment.validate() && validator.validate()) {

        checkout.setLoadWaiting('checkout-step-billing', false, true);

        var request = new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveUrl,
            {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: formData,
                onComplete: this.onComplete,
                onSuccess: this.onSave,
                onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
            }
        );
    }
```

**OnepageController.php :**

```
    public function saveOrderAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }

    $result = array();
    //
    // Upload doc if order weapons
    //

    /* get order id */
    $quoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getId();

    $folder = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'downloadable' . DS . 'doc_armes' . DS . $quoteId;
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    var_dump($data);
    try {
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx', 'pdf'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        if (!is_dir($folder)) {
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
        }
        $uploader->save($folder, $data);
        $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = true;
    }
```

and var_dump($data) return :

[image]

I don't know how to get all files...

Thanks for help !

Comment: Use $_FILES to get uploading file data.

Comment: $_FILES return an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can not achieve this via Magento prototype.js file***

***You have to make some customization in js file***

you can try below code to upload file, data via js and submit.

```
document
  .querySelector('#testForm')
  .addEventListener('submit', function processForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('processForm');

    var form = e.currentTarget;
    var formData = new FormData();

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      form.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]'),
      function (input, i) {
        // use the input name, don't invent another one
        if (input.value) formData.append(input.name, input.files[0]);
      }
    );

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // use the form info, don't couple your JS with an end-point
    request.open(form.method, form.action);
    // want to distinguish from non-JS submits?
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    request.send(formData);

    request.onload = function(e) {
        console.log('Request Status', request.status);
    };
  })
;
```

You can follow below link also.

[How can i upload a file using prototype js ajax call](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62962/how-can-i-upload-a-file-using-prototype-js-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$uploader->save($folder, $_FILES['attachment']['name'])
```

instead of

```
$uploader->save($folder, $data);
```